# pass briefe to another detailed form

Tags: vba

My code should search a sheet of my selection and show the results in a listbox(in briefe) then if I double click my selection it shows a message to open either show or modify which it does but when trying to view the detailed results it only shows the last row in the list box here is the code:
Dim MySheet As Worksheet

```
Private Sub LBResult_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim answer As Integer
    If Me.TbSearch = "" Then
    
        Me.TbSearch.SetFocus
    Else
        answer = MsgBox("áÚÑÖ ÇáÊÝÇÕíá ÇÖÛØ YES ááÊÚÏíá ÇÖÛØ no ", vbYesNoCancel)
        If answer = vbYes Then
            Unload Me
            'If frmDetails.LBResult.Column(2, frmDetails.LBResult.ListIndex).Value <> "" Then
    
            'MsgBox "found it"
            '
            frmDetails.Show
            'End If
        ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
            Unload Me
            frmMod.Show
        End If
    
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TbSearch_Change()
    Dim I As Long
    With MySheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Set edRng = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    Me.LBResult.Clear
    
    If CBRoads <> "" Then
        For I = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(edRng)
            For x = 1 To 59
                a = Len(Me.TbSearch.Text)
                If Left(MySheet.Cells(I, x).Value, a) = Me.TbSearch.Text And Me.TbSearch.Text <> "" Then
    
                    Me.LBResult.AddItem MySheet.Cells(I, 1).Value
    
          
                    Me.LBResult.List(LBResult.ListCount - 1, 0) = MySheet.Cells(I, 2).Value
                    Me.LBResult.List(LBResult.ListCount - 1, 1) = MySheet.Cells(I, 3).Value
                    Me.LBResult.List(LBResult.ListCount - 1, 2) = MySheet.Cells(I, 1).Value
                    Me.LBResult.List(LBResult.ListCount - 1, 3) = MySheet.Cells(I, 51).Value
                    Me.LBResult.List(LBResult.ListCount - 1, 4) = MySheet.Cells(I, 56).Value
    
    
                    If Me.LBResult.Selected(LBResult.ListIndex) = True Then
                        frmDetails.tbVioNo = MySheet.Cells(I, 1).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioCompany = MySheet.Cells(I, 2).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioOwner = MySheet.Cells(I, 3).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioRoad = MySheet.Cells(I, 4).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioLocation = MySheet.Cells(I, 5).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioCount = MySheet.Cells(I, 6).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioLength = MySheet.Cells(I, 7).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioWidth = MySheet.Cells(I, 8).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioFaces = MySheet.Cells(I, 9).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioAnnual = MySheet.Cells(I, 10).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioExpenses = MySheet.Cells(I, 11).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioEngineering = MySheet.Cells(I, 12).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTax = MySheet.Cells(I, 13).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTotal = MySheet.Cells(I, 14).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioCount1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 15).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioLength1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 16).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioWidth1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 17).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioFaces1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 18).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioAnnual1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 19).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioExpenses1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 20).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioEngineering1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 21).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTax1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 22).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTotal1 = MySheet.Cells(I, 23).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioCount2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 24).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioLength2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 25).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioWidth2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 26).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioFaces2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 27).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioAnnual2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 28).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioExpenses2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 29).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioEngineering2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 30).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTax2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 31).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTotal2 = MySheet.Cells(I, 32).Value
                        'ÇáÇÚáÇä ÇáÑÇÈÚ
                        frmDetails.tbVioCount3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 33).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioLength3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 34).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioWidth3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 35).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioFaces3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 36).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioAnnual3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 37).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioExpenses3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 38).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioEngineering3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 39).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTax3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 40).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTotal3 = MySheet.Cells(I, 41).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioCount4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 42).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioLength4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 43).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioWidth4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 44).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioFaces4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 45).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioAnnual4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 46).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioExpenses4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 47).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioEngineering4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 48).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTax4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 49).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTotal4 = MySheet.Cells(I, 50).Value
    
    
                        frmDetails.tbVioDate = MySheet.Cells(I, 51).Value
                        frmDetails.tbVioTybe = MySheet.Cells(I, 52).Value
                        'ÈíäÇÊ ÕÇÍÈ ÇáãÎÇáÝÉ
                        frmDetails.tbAddress = MySheet.Cells(I, 53).Value
                        frmDetails.tbORegion = MySheet.Cells(I, 54).Value
                        frmDetails.tbOGovern = MySheet.Cells(I, 55).Value
    
                        frmDetails.tbVioGtotal = MySheet.Cells(I, 56).Value
    
                    End If
    
                End If
            Next x
    
        Next I
    Else
    
        Me.CBRoads.SetFocus
    End If
    
End Sub
```

My comments is in Arabic so it will not appear properly.

Comment: This code will not compile because of an extra `End Sub`.  Please fix your post.

Comment: Welcome! When debugging VBA it's helpful to add `Option Explicit` at the very top of the module. This will force you to ensure variables and properties are properly declared/handled.  Also check out "[ask]", as well as **how to create a [MCVE]** and update the code in your question so others can better help you.

Comment: these are to events one on double click and the other on form opening

Comment: @AhmedGammal we can't help you if we can' reproduce the problem.  This code will not compile.

Comment: modified the code

Answer (score 0):

I would change these lines.  The idea is to put stops in the code to inspect your variables.

```
If CBRoads <> "" Then
    For I = 2 To edRng.Rows.Count + 1
        Rem  Inspect edRng and make sure that it includes all the cells that you expect it to include..
        Application.Goto edRng
        
        Rem Press F5 to continue to the next stop
        Stop
        For x = 1 To 59
            a = Len(Me.TbSearch.Text)
            If Left(MySheet.Cells(I, x).Value, a) = Me.TbSearch.Text And Me.TbSearch.Text <> "" Then
                
                Debug.Print MySheet.Cells(I, 1).Address
                
                Rem Press F5 to continue to the next stop
                Stop
```

Comment: $A$2
$A$3
$A$3
$A$4
$A$5